# System.Windows - Events - Opening - Powershell

Tags: c#, xaml

Im trying to create a progress bar for one of my computer configuration scripts and I'd like to avoid adding a button or some kind of trigger to the GUI,

The script is powershell and for the GUI XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="BackUp_MAINWINDOW" x:Class="ProgressBarTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProgressBarTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="88%" Height="110" Width="510" Icon="C:\Users\rsosa012\Documents\Scripts\Powershell\ICOs\PwC.ico" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Top="0" FontFamily="Georgia" Margin="0,-1,0,0" FontSize="11" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="0">
<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TaskbarItemInfo Description="Progress" ProgressState="Indeterminate" ProgressValue="50"/>
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Margin="10,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410" Value="50" Opacity="0.6"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="435,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Source="C:\Users\rsosa012\Documents\Scripts\Powershell\ICOs\PwC.ico"/>
    <Label Content="Name: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="10,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" FontFamily="Georgia" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label Content="Items remaining: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="10,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" FontFamily="Georgia" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" Margin="392,28,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="88%" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" FontSize="12" Opacity="0.6"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="11" Margin="51,12,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" FontSize="9"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="11" Margin="106,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" FontSize="9"/>

</Grid>
```

My question is about the events of these controls, does any of these controls have an event that triggers when the .showdialog() method executes, basically when the window appears?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could use the `Loaded` event. The event is fired if the window is loaded for the first time. Otherwise `IsVisibleChanged` could help.

Comment: Futhermore it's not clear to me what do you mean with "I'd like to avoid adding a button or some kind of trigger to the GUI".

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, when I looked at the loaded event the description sounded like it would trigger multiple times

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'mt not sure about the `Loaded` event and I can't test it at the moment. I hope I could help you.